# Can we have more polite statement for closing a question as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When we mark a question (say A) duplicate of other question (say B), the following sentence appears in the comment section by default.

> Possible duplicate of "question B"

Instead of that can we have more polite sentence which would say

> Your question already has an answer here.
>   You may find an answer to your question here.
>   Same question was already asked before.

Is it possible to have one of these statements in the place of current format? If none of the above are good, give your own choice of sentences.

Comment: I think "Possible duplicate" is polite. I think all SE sites have the same statement.

Comment: When "possible duplicate format" is used on other site, that user freaked out saying "Everyone are trying to close my question. Better search using google."

Comment: I actually like the current one better. Reason is, unless others also vote and agree to the closure, a "possible" duplicate will not become a "confirmed" duplicate. It also gives a chance to OP to edit the question and remove the duplicate part if it's not an exact duplicate. Also, this is by design. Don't think mods here can customize this for our site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an automatic comment rather than a statement.

From [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/260388)

> **What are automatic comments?**
>
> In several cases, the system will automatically add comments to posts on your behalf. You still own the comment, and it will appear the same as if you had manually posted the comment. You may delete the comment if you desire, but this is discouraged as it is helpful to the original poster: the automatic comments provide information on how to improve the post or why it is not appropriate.
>
> When someone flags or votes to close a question as an exact duplicate, the system automatically posts a comment to that question which reads **"possible duplicate of -link-"**, as long as no such link has already been posted in a comment. The comment will be automatically deleted if the question is closed as a duplicate.

This mechanism had feature requested as [Autocomment when voting to close as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44173/260388).

Now, talking to the point, comments are considered less important than posts and statements.

Well, we've already *polite* banner to  the questioner when question get duplicate close vote:

> **The question may have already an answer here:**
> [Title of question](link to the question)

Also, the close statement after question get closed is also fine:

> This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question

Anyway, the owner of comment is free to edit or delete the comment.

Comment: "The question may have already an answer here:" . This is what I am talking about. I didn't remember that there is a banner like this.